# Better notation for norm

Tags: notation

Is there a better notation for the norm of a vector? For example, if I have a set of vectors $X$, then the set of norms associated with it would be

$$
\{||x|| \mid x \in X\}
$$

The vertical norm lines look identical to the set builder vertical line. The vertical lines only start to get more confusing from there. Say I want to get the number of vectors with their norm in a certain range $[r_1, r_2]$ (by set cardinality notation, which is also a vertical bar)

$$
|\{x \mid ||x|| \in [r_1, r_2]\}|
$$

which seems very confusing. Any better notations?

Comment: You know the notation $\{\lVert x\rVert:x\in X\}$ exists, right?  Also use `\|` or friends instead of `||`.

Comment: The norm notation is pretty standard. What you can do is change the vertical bar in the set builder notation to a colon, I.e. $\{\|x\| : x \in X\}$, which is also standard.

Comment: Great idea, user10354138 and Sambo!

Comment: I am also considering the double bar cardinality notation. i.e. $|X| = \overline{\overline{X}}$, from Wikipedia article on cardinality ([link](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cardinality))